# Apache gora, where to set new table name in reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, gora

I have an application that is basically an Hbase Mapreduce job with Apache Gora.
I am very simple case that I want to copy one Hbase table data to a new table. Where to write new table name. I have reviewed [this Guide](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.apache.gora.mapreduce.GoraMapper) but could not find where to put new table name.
Following is the code snippet,

```
/* Mappers are initialized with GoraMapper.initMapper() or 
   * GoraInputFormat.setInput()*/
  GoraMapper.initMapperJob(job, inStore, TextLong.class, LongWritable.class,
      LogAnalyticsMapper.class, true);

  /* Reducers are initialized with GoraReducer#initReducer().
   * If the output is not to be persisted via Gora, any reducer 
   * can be used instead. */
  GoraReducer.initReducerJob(job, outStore, LogAnalyticsReducer.class);
```

Simple MR job is very easy for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will redirect you to the [tutorial](http://gora.apache.org/current/tutorial.html), but I will try to clarify here :)

The table name is defined in you mappings. Check [Table Mappings](http://gora.apache.org/current/tutorial.html#defining-data-store-mappings). Maybe you have a file called `gora-hbase-mapping.xml` where the mapping is defined.
There should be something like this:

```
<table name="Nameofatable">
...
<class name="blah.blah.EntityA" keyClass="java.lang.Long" table="Nameofatable">
```

There you configure the table name (put the same name if you find both). There can be several `<table>` and `<class>`. Maybe one for your input and one for your output.

AFTER that, you have to instantiate your input/output datastores `inStore` and `outStore`. The tutorial got a bit messy and the creation of `inStore` and `outStore` got [to the wrong section](http://gora.apache.org/current/tutorial.html#spark-backend). You just do something like:

```
inStore = DataStoreFactory.getDataStore(String.class, EntityA.class, hadoopConf);
outStore = DataStoreFactory.getDataStore(Long.class, OtherEntity.class, hadoopConf);
```

---

Explanation "in the other way":

- You instantiate the datastore with `DataStoreFactory.getDatastore(key class, entity class, conf).`
- The entity class requested is looked into `gora-hbase-mapping.xml` for `<class name="blah.blah.EntityA"`.
- In that `<class>` it is the attribute `table=`. ***That is your table name*** :)

So: you define an entity as input with its table name, and you define an entity as ouput with its table name

---

EDIT 1:

If the **entity class is the same, but the table names are different**, the only solution I can think of is creating two classes `Entity1` and `Entity2` with the same schema and in your `gora-hbase-mapping.xml` create two `<table>` and `<class>`.
Then instantiante the stores like:

```
inStore = DataStoreFactory.getDataStore(String.class, Entity1.class, hadoopConf);
outStore = DataStoreFactory.getDataStore(String.class, Entity2.class, hadoopConf);
```

It is not very clean but it should work :\

---

EDIT 2 (not for this question):

If the source table and the destination table are the same, there is a version for initReducerJob that allows this behavior.An example is in [Nutch's `GeneratorJob.java`](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/release-2.3.1/src/java/org/apache/nutch/crawl/GeneratorJob.java#L220):

```
StorageUtils.initMapperJob(currentJob, fields, SelectorEntry.class, WebPage.class, GeneratorMapper.class, SelectorEntryPartitioner.class, true);
StorageUtils.initReducerJob(currentJob, GeneratorReducer.class);
```

Comment: Thanks brother. For my use case, it is actually Apache Nutch. I was thinking as you guided. But how I can handle two different tables (source + sink) with same schema in one job. For my case, I have to copy one Hbase table (created by Nutch) to a new table.

Comment: Both entities belong to same class in my case.

Comment: Updated the answer. Basically, treat the input and output like if they were different classes (will have to create another entity class though will be almost equal)